# Using kernlab::kqr(reduced = TRUE), how is the y argument missing in the call to csi()?

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing, quantile-regression, cholesky-decomposition

I'm trying to perform a kernelized quantile regression on some data using the function `kqr()` from the `kernlab` package in R. The regression runs on some portions of my data, but on other portions, I run into invertibility issues, so at the advice of my team, I'm trying to make use of the Cholesky decomposition functionality in the package. Here is some sample code below that reproduces the error:

```
library(kernlab)
x = as.matrix(sort(sample(seq(from = 5, to = 29),100, replace = TRUE)))
y = as.matrix(sample(seq(from = 0, to = 36)/36, 100, replace = TRUE))
kqr(x = x, y = y,
   ​tau = .85,
   ​kernel = "rbfdot",
   ​kpar = list(sigma = 10),
   ​reduced = TRUE)
```

Setting `reduced = TRUE` produces this error:

```
Error in csi(x, kernel = kernel, rank = rank) : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

First I checked the documentation for `csi()`, the relevant bit of which reads:

```
csi(x, y, kernel="rbfdot", kpar=list(sigma=0.1), rank,
centering = TRUE, kappa = 0.99 ,delta = 40 ,tol = 1e-5)
```

`csi()` is indeed looking for a `y` argument, so then I checked what `csi()` is actually doing by viewing the actual implementation in R, since `y` is clearly specified in the call to `kqr()`. I called `getMethod("kqr","matrix")` and I found where `csi()` is called in the function. This is what I found:

```
if (!reduced) 
            H = kernelMatrix(kernel, x)
        else H = csi(x, kernel = kernel, rank = rank)
```

It looks to me like `y` really *isn't* being passed through from `kqr()` to `csi()` when `reduced = TRUE`.

I recognize the arrogance in so quickly assuming a bug in the code, but I don't know how else to make sense of the error. Am I naively using the function incorrectly? If this is indeed a bug, how should I go about remedying the function to make it usable with `reduced = TRUE`? If this is not a bug, then can anyone see how I need to specify my function call to `kqr()` so that `csi()` inherits the `y` argument properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are using this function correctly. This could be a bug in the code (`y` is not passed to `csi`). You could try to contact the [maintainer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html) of the `kernlab` package for clarification. See also instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644680/r-whats-the-proper-way-to-overwrite-a-function-from-a-package).

### Temporary solution

To get the function run, you could temporarely change `kqr` using `trace`.

Once you use `trace` an editor will open.
Edit the `csi` call (line 79) to: `else H = csi(x, as.matrix(y), kernel = kernel, rank = rank)`

Then the `kqr` should work properly.

At the end you can stop the tracing with:

```
untrace(kqr,signature="matrix")
```

### Example code

```r
#load library
library(kernlab)

# example data
x = as.matrix(sort(sample(seq(from = 5, to = 29),100, replace = TRUE)))
y = as.matrix(sample(seq(from = 0, to = 36)/36, 100, replace = TRUE))

# trace function and enable edit
# edit kqr according to the explanations above
trace("kqr",signature="matrix",edit=TRUE)
#> [1] "kqr"

#run (check edits again)
kqr(x = x, y = y,
    tau = .85,
    kernel = "rbfdot",
    kpar = list(sigma = 10),
    reduced = TRUE)
#> Tracing function ".local" in package "kernlab"
#> Kernel Quantile Regression object of class "kqr" 
#> 
#> Gaussian Radial Basis kernel function. 
#>  Hyperparameter : sigma =  10 
#> 
#> Regularization Cost Parameter C:  0.1
#> Number of training instances learned : 100 
#> Train error :  pinball loss :  0.215005418  rambloss : 0.85

#stop tracing
untrace(kqr,signature="matrix")
#> Untracing specified method for function "kqr" in environment
#> <namespace:kernlab>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! One question though, why do I need to specify `x1` and `y1`? Couldn't I just insert `y` in the call to `csi()`? Also, you meant `y1=y`, not `y2=y` I assume?

Comment: `kqr` does some internal transformation, however, you can just add `as.matrix(y)` within `csi`, I adjusted my answer. Do you get the expected result now?

Comment: Yes I do get the expected result now, but is there a way to save my changes so that it doesn't pop up the trace window for editing every time the function is called? I will eventually be calling `kqr` many times and I'd have to click "save" on the `trace` window each time

Comment: Furthermore, while trying to use the `cross = 10` argument, the function fails after the second call, with this error: `Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  assignment of an object of class “character” is not valid for @‘kpar’ in an object of class “kqr”; is(value, "list") is not TRUE`. I've tried using `subset` to specify a training set, but `cross > 1` is supposed to do that already. And I'm not sure how to specify a range of `C` values within this function either, since `kpar` takes only kernel parameters, not model parameters.

Comment: For a permanent solution check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644680/r-whats-the-proper-way-to-overwrite-a-function-from-a-package). Regarding `cross`, I also get this error without any changes of the package code. You probably have to open a new question regarding this.

Comment: Regarding `cross`, I figured as much. I'll use that permanent solution you mentioned for `trace`, thank you so much for your help here.